# Git hub repository pages inside the nested folder are not ranking

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, ranking, github, git

I have a git hub repository for hackerrank solutions which is ranking very well.

Here is the link- https://github.com/Java-aid/Hackerrank-Solutions

My repository is ranking well if someone searches for hackerrank solutions but it's not ranking for files and folder which are present in the nested folder in the repository.

**ex-** https://github.com/Java-aid/Hackerrank-Solutions/blob/master/HackerRankDashboard/CoreCS/GeneralProgramming/src/main/java/com/javaaid/hackerrank/solutions/generalprogramming/basicprogramming/DrawingBook.java

people are not able to find the solution for drawingbook.java

If anybody search drawingBook it's not ranking at all. Can anybody explain why and provide the solution for the same?

What I should do to rank my java programs?

**Note:** I really dont understand whether this question should be a part of seo or not because its related to git hub repository.

Comment: I don't it has anything to do with being in a folder.  Where are you linking to that page?  Is that same code also found on some other page, even on another site?

Comment: If you open the first link ( https://github.com/Java-aid/Hackerrank-Solutions) you can see all pages are linked from there. its the index page to find all the solutions.

and this code is not present anywhere apart from git hub.

Comment: just now i noticed that i have two readme.md file inside my repository. one under

 https://github.com/Java-aid/Hackerrank-Solutions

and one under
https://github.com/Java-aid/Hackerrank-Solutions/tree/master/HackerRankDashboard

and one is updated and other is not?  is this the reason?

Comment: It could be a problem for those particular pages.   When Google finds the same content on two URLs it usually chooses one of the two to index.  See: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: I have gone through the shared link. just wanted to confirm once. if i remove one readme then google will be able to index it properly or something else i need to do to force google to crawl my git hub repository again??

Comment: Google comes back and crawls periodically.  If you change your site you don't need to request anything.

Comment: As the duplicate question says, not getting indexed is usually because:  1. Google hasn't found it yet because it is new or not linked to, 2.  Google can't crawl it because it is blocked, 3. Google found a duplicate somewhere and indexes that instead or 4.  Your site doesn't have enough reputation to get everything on it indexed.